# How to detect compatibility between delegate types?

Tags: c#, types, delegates

I have a test like this:

```
receivingType.IsAssignableFrom(exportingType))
```

Which works most of the time, but does not return the desired result when the types involved are delegate types. For example, if exportingType is `Action<object, EventArgs>` and receivingType is `EventHandler`, I want the result to be true but the above expression is false. The result I am looking for is `true` since the two delegates have equivalent method signatures and in fact in C# are actually assignable to each other (although I understand that's probably C# syntax magic).

So my question is, what would the equivalent test look like for delegates that would provide the desired compatibility result?

Comment: Hmm. Generic covariance and contravariance starts making this significantly harder...

Answer (score 3):

If you choose to ignore parameter/return type covariance/contravariance (both the variance supported by the compiler since C# 2.0 and the generic covariant/contravariance with `in` / `out`), demanding just equality of types, you could use:

```
public static bool AreCompatible(Type delegate1, Type delegate2)
{
    MethodInfo method1 = delegate1.GetMethod("Invoke");
    MethodInfo method2 = delegate1.GetMethod("Invoke");

    return method1.ReturnType == method2.ReturnType &&
           method1.GetParameters().Select(p => p.ParameterType)
                  .SequenceEqual(method2.GetParameters()
                                         .Select(p => p.ParameterType));
}
```

(As noted in comments, you might also want to check for out/ref parameters...)

Comment: Could also check `ParameterInfo`'s `IsOut` as well as `Type`'s `IsByRef` (note that `out` is `IsByRef` so a nice combination of the two can uniquely identify `ref` vs `out`) (Also, I do understand that `delegate` cannot have `ref` nor `out` parameters - but `MethodInfo` isn't tied to user defined delegates only, just in case OP wanted something more)

Comment: Indeed! I misspoke. I did not mean `delegate`, I meant ref is not part of the Type, but a modifier, thus can't be used with just any generic argument (such as `T` with `Action<T>`). Of course, the user could define their own `delegate` and declare a parameter is ref or out. (oh how I wish stackoverflow would allow me to save face and edit a comment 23 minutes old)

Answer (score 0):

It turned out the below worked very well for me. While I haven't verified that it handles the generic type arg covariance and all that complexity, I suspect it does, and I didn't have to do any of it. :)

```
internal static bool IsAssignableFrom(Type importingDelegate, Type exportingDelegate)
{
    Type importingDelegate, exportingDelegate; // assigned elsewhere
    MethodInfo exportingDelegateMethod = exportingDelegate.GetMethod("Invoke");
    try
    {
        exportingDelegateMethod.CreateDelegate(importingDelegate, null);
        return true;
    }
    catch (ArgumentException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Since I'm in a portable library, `Type.GetMethod` doesn't exist, and `Type.GetRuntimeMethod` doesn't seem to fit. So the above only works outside of a portable library.

For the portable library, I happened to already have the `MethodInfo` of the exporting method, so I could skip the GetMethod call and go straight to the `CreateDelegate` test.

Comment: For PCL targeted folks, `Type.GetTypeInfo().DeclaredMethods` may work to obtain the `MethodInfo`